# Automatically suppress multicol layout if available space is too narrow

Tags: multicol

I am using pdfLaTeX (in MikTex) to write technical articles for a company newsletter.

Inside any one article I switch between two column layout for descriptive text and one column layout for code segments, figures, tables etc.

```
%newsletterA4.text
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\input{editorial.tex}
\input{article1.tex}
\input{article2.tex}
\end{document}
```

A typical article file:

```
% article1.tex
Headings go over the full text width

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum 
\end{multicols}

\begin{verbatim}
code listing (or figure or image go over the full text width) 
\end{verbatim}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}
```

The articles I write, are occasionally published also in different media

1. with smaller `\textwidth` and/or
2. inside a (narrow) minipage

In future all articles may also be published in

3. html on the company's intranet

In those scenarios I prefer a single column layout.
Currently, I run a script creating an alternative version of the article file, commenting out the `\begin{multicols}` and `\end{multicols}`. Not exactly elegant

Is there a way that LaTeX takes care of this automatically?
Something like:
*If `\textwidth` is smaller than some value then ignore the multicol environment.*

Does a minipage have its own `\textwidth` parameter so the test would be possible as well?

I admit, I have not looked into the latex2html topic yet (no web presence yet) but I thought I mention it in case it influences the answers.
I would appreciate a hint how I could "ignore" multicol for publishing in html.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a new environment `mymulticols` in this way

```
\newenvironment{mymulticols}[1]
  {\ifdim\textwidth<\mylength\else\begin{multicols}{#1}\fi}
  {\ifdim\textwidth<\mylength\else\end{multicols}\fi}
```

so that if `\textwidth` < `\mylength`, `multicols` is not used, otherwise it is.

Set the length of `\mylength` to the needed value. In this example I've set

```
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{20cm}
```

and since `\textwidth` < `20cm` in this case, `multicols` is discarded.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{20cm}

\newenvironment{mymulticols}[1]
  {\ifdim\textwidth<\mylength\else\begin{multicols}{#1}\fi}
  {\ifdim\textwidth<\mylength\else\end{multicols}\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{mymulticols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{mymulticols}

\begin{verbatim}
code listing (or figure or image go over the full text width)
\end{verbatim}

\begin{mymulticols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{mymulticols}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you change the value of `\mylength` to `10cm` you will get:

[image]

Comment: By the way: It works on minipages as well!

Comment: @Phil You're welcome. Inside `minipage`s the value of `\textwidth` changes accordingly to the width of the `minipage`, so it works there too :-)